# Automated go app deployment

Tags: deployment, go

I'm wondering if there are any convenient ways to automate deployment of code to a live server in GO, either standard built-in methods, or otherwise.

I want something google app engine like, I just run the command and it uploads to the server and triggers a restart.

(Ultimately I want a git commit to trigger a rebuild and redeploy, but thats for down the track in the future)

Comment: The nice thing about Go is that you don't need to run Git on the receiving end: which makes worrying about versioning, keeping your server in-sync with your dev environment (etc) a non-issue. Set up a post-commit hook on your local git server(s) and/or use a CI system like Travis CI (as per @Fabio Gomes' answer) run your tests, build your app and push the binary *only* to your server. Stop the existing, start the new one and off you go. No need to install/config a git server or Go on the server!

Comment: @elithrar yes, that's one of the best things about Go. And as you pointed it out, most CI servers like Travis can deploy using FTP for example: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/ so if you'd like to deploy to a custom server or a vps you just need to use Travis to build and deploy the binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend [Travis CI](http://travis-ci.org) + [Heroku](http://heroku.com).

You can deploy to heroku directly with just a git push, but I like to use Travis to build and run the tests before that.

There are some guides online but I'll try to go directly to the point:

What you will need?

- Github account
- Travis account (linked with github, free if open source)
- Empty [Heroku](http://heroku.com) app (Free dyno works great)

**Setup**

In your github repo, create the following files:

- .travis.yml (more info on the [Travis CI documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go/))
- Procfile
- .go-dir

After that go to your Travis account, add your repository and enabled the build for it.

Here is a sample minimal config file content (based on my app that I deploy to heroku):

**.travis.yml**

```
language: go
go:
  - tip
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  buildpack: https://github.com/kr/heroku-buildpack-go.git
  api_key:
    secure: <your heroku api key encripted with travis encrypt>
  on: master
```

**Procfile**

```
worker: your-app-binary
```

**.go-dir**

```
your-app-binary
```

Procfile and .go-dir are heroku configs so it can vary if you are deploying a web app, you can read more at the [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

One important and easily missed point is the **build pack**, without it the deploy will not work.

Read the Travis docs to see how to [encrypt the heroku key](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/)

**How it works?**

Basically, every push to your repository will trigger the Travis CI build, if it passes it will deploy the app to heroku, so you set this up once and build + deploy is just a push away ;)

Also Travis will build and updated the status of all Pull Requests to your repository automagically.

To see my config and build, please take a look at my [Travis build](https://travis-ci.org/fabioxgn/go-bot-heroku) and [my repository](https://github.com/fabioxgn/go-bot-heroku) with my working configs

Comment: Very good answer. Some extra tools that may be worth looking into are https://github.com/etsy/deployinator/ , https://github.com/racker/dreadnot .

Comment: Heroku does not support GO. Travis CI costs $129US per year for a small organisation/startup.

Comment: @Jacob Heroku doesn't support oficially, buit it supports custom build packs and there is a very good one for Go. Also, that's what I recommend based on simplicity of deployment and "hassle free" solution. If you'd like a free solution there's plenty around and as Go compiles to a single binary, you can always write your own.